# PCI configuration address space

Tags: pci

Where is the PCI configuration address space located at? Is it located in the main system memory? If yes, is this memory address space predefined (hardwire) or change after each reboot?

Comment: Look [here at OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Configuration_Space).

Comment: okay zx485 but still confused...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCI configuration space is present in PCI card and it is mapped to CPU addressible space. In fact, every PCI function has its own configuration space.